# Python 3: Cannot insert values received from Arduino into MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, arduino, raspberry-pi

Hope you're all doing fine.

I have a problem I've been trying to solve for a good while now without success.

I have this Arduino script written that reads the values registered by the DHT11 sensor and prints them out to serial. Here is the code:

```
#include <dht11.h>
#define DHT11PIN 2

dht11 DHT11;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);

}

void loop()
{
  Serial.println();

  int chk = DHT11.read(DHT11PIN);
  float h = DHT11.humidity; //read humidity
  float t = DHT11.temperature; //read temperature (C)

  Serial.print(h);
  Serial.print("%");
  Serial.print(t);

  delay(2000);

}
```

My intention was to take the above data printed on serial, and send it to the python code which would then insert the received data into the MySQL data base I've created. It all seems to be working fine up until the reception part, but when I try to insert the received data into my data base I get all sorts of different errors no matter how I'm trying to process the data.

First, when I try to use the code below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import serial
import mysql.connector as connector
import re

#the following have been changed so that I don't expose the real details

__dsn = {
            "host": "localhost",
            "user": "user",
            "passwd": "passwd",
            "db": "sensor"
        }

dbConn = connector.connect(**__dsn)

#open a cursor to the database
cursor = dbConn.cursor()

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 115200)
humidity = 0
temperature = 0

while 1:

        #data = ser.read()
        data = ser.read(1)
        n = ser.inWaiting()

        if n:

            data = data + ser.read(n)

        data = data.decode("UTF-8")

        try:

            pieces = data.split('%')  #split the data by the tab

            humidity = pieces[0]
            temperature = pieces[1]



        except IndexError:
            pass

        a = humidity
        b = temperature


        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO environment(humidity,temperature) VALUES (%s,%s)", (a,b))
        dbConn.commit()
        cursor.close()
```

I get this error:

[image]

I've also tried to change both humidity and temperature values to float type, but if I do so, I get this error:

[image]

I'm not sure what is happening here. I've tried to process the data in many ways. Here are the examples of the data processing methods I've tried to use so far:

```
        humidity.replace(" ", "")
        temperature.replace(" ", "")

        a = float(humidity).notnull()
        b = float(temperature).notnull()

        float(re.sub(r'[^0-9\.]', '', a))
        float(re.sub(r'[^0-9\.]', '', b))
```

Again, no success...

I'd be very grateful if somebody could point me in the right direction.

Thank you

Rob

Comment: You seem to send numeric data, but then you try to treat it as string in python (`data.decode("UTF-8")`). This does not sound right to me!

Comment: could you also add the values that you try to insert into the database and also the create table of enviroment

Comment: I think you'll see immediately what is wrong if you put `print(data)` right below `data = data.decode("UTF-8")`…

Comment: Hi. Thanks for all your answers. I've been trying to fix my code according to your advice. When I remove the data.decode("UTF-8) line from the code I get the following error: "a bytes-like object is required not 'str'". Arduino sends a '%' sign along with the values which is treated as a string which may be where the problem is. I'd appreciate any further advice. Thank you very much guys.

Answer (score 0):

I just 'fixed' the problem. I noticed that the Arduino would occasionally send a string with weird characters attached to the actual number (like )54.00) or missing a part of a number (instead of sending 54.00 it'd send 4.00). This mostly occurs with the humidity values, temperature read is almost always correct.

I am not sure why that is (possibly a hardware issue) but the way I went around that issue is adding the following to the code:

'''

```
    try:
        float(humidity)
    except:
        humidity = 0.0

    try:
        float(temperature)
    except:
        temperature = 0.0
```

'''

So every error would be interpreted as just Arduino sending a '0.0' value. If anybody knows of a cleaner way of fixing it I could still use some suggestions. Thank you!